# How to customise KrakenD gateway to monetise an API?

Tags: architecture, api-gateway, system-design, krakend

I'm having KrakenD as API gateway for backend services. I wish to monetize one API in KrakenD gateway. But, how do I use Krakend HTTP server plugin for same? Do I put the request, response using this plugin in queue and then consumer puts it in database? Or is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [KrakenD HTTP Server Plugin](https://www.krakend.io/docs/extending/http-server-plugins/).

Depending on your monetization strategy, this plugin can be used to log the request and response information for billing purposes. You can also create a consumer-side application that would store the request/response information in a database, keeping track of how many requests/responses to each resource were made, and the identity of the consumer.

You can then charge your customers using that information and a billing service like Stripe.